# Solr: Separate highlight fragment for each search term occurrence

Tags: solr, highlighting, solrj

I use Solr 5 for searching in large (text) documents. For each search result, I display a fragment containing the highlighted search match. This works nicley using Solr's [Standard Highlighter](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Standard+Highlighter). Yet I found that if several matches are found close to each other, they will be merged into one fragment, even with `hl.mergeContiguous=false`. Params are

```
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
query.setQuery(rawQuery);
query.set("defType", "lucene");
query.setRows(1000);
query.setHighlight(true);
query.setHighlightFragsize(200);
query.setHighlightSnippets(20);
query.setParam("hl.fl", "content");
query.setParam("hl.maxAnalyzedChars", "-1");
query.setParam("hl.mergeContiguous", false);
```

Example: I use a bible translation for testing, just because of its length. Searching for *beast* yields (among many others)

> ...7:8 Of clean *beasts*, and of *beasts* that are not clean, and of birds, and of everything that creeps upon the ground, 7:9 there went in two and two to Noah into...

I would rather have this fragment twice, because it contains two occurrences of the search term. Manually duplicating the fragment in this case appears clumsy to me. Am I missing a query parameter, or do I need a custom `BoundaryScanner` to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can think of using `hl.regex` - regex based fragmenter, and prepare the regex based on your terms and attach to the request. look for related `hl.regex.slop`, `hl.regex.maxAnalyzedChars` params also if you want to try this.

Or can reduce the fragment size for standard highlighter: `hl.fragsize` to something you think two occurrences of your terms may not be existing within.

`BoundaryScanner` works with `FastVectorHighlighter` only, and can be the option if no OOTB param works.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting. Actually I am content with how the fragments look like, so I feel reluctant to changing their size or pattern for creation. I guess the cause lies deeper why Solr is merging fragments with results close to each other. I will take a look at `BoundaryScanner` though.